# What’s the difference between due to lockdown and due to a lockdown? Can I use article before the word lock down?

Tags: grammar, articles, nouns, spoken-english, uncountable-nouns

People are working from home due to lockdown or people are working from home due to a lockdown? Which one is true? And why the other one is not true incase one of the usages is not correct?

Comment: Both are 'true' in that many people are indeed working from home. Lockdown is a worldwide phenomenon, so everyone knows what you are talking about. You would only say _a lockdown_ if it was something happening in one district that people elsewhere didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since there is a lockdown in the whole world, you probably would say 'due to lockdown'. However, that is not completely crystal clear. The best way of saying this would be 'due to THE lockdown'. That would be more clear to the audience.